# Are there any other ways of speeding up the building of Bitcoin Core PRs other than ccache?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, compiling, cache

I am already using [ccache](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/99097/what-is-ccache-when-should-i-use-it-when-building-and-reviewing-bitcoin-core-pr) to speed up recompilation when building Bitcoin Core PRs. Are there any other ways of speeding up the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will Clark answered this question on IRC.

You can reduce the time it takes to run `./configure` by using `./configure -q -C`. `-q` is quiet and `-C` removes terminal printing and uses a cache (like ccache). It reduced Will's configure time from 29 seconds to 10 seconds. For more details see this [info page](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.60/html_node/Cache-Files.html).