# What is in the Bitcoin Core LevelDB dbcache? Is it full records or metadata?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, database, leveldb, cache

What is in the Bitcoin Core LevelDB [dbcache](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/89100/bitcoind-node-crashes-after-using-dbcache-option)? Is it full records or metadata?

This question was asked on IRC by Anonymous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bitcoin Core [documentation](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/0d71395848bbc2941862e7a0644f47212ec02e87/doc/reduce-memory.md#in-memory-caches) describes dbcache as the cache for the UTXO database.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) describes a cache as a:

> software component that stores data so that future requests for that data can be served faster; the data stored in a cache might be the result of an earlier computation or a copy of data stored elsewhere.

Greg Maxwell added on IRC:

> There are basically two separate uses: the block index which is
> essentially metadata and the UTXO database.
>
> The dbcache is not really a cache, it's a write buffer and it prevents
> needing to sync the disk or make random writes. As a cache it doesn't
> do much and isn't needed for that. It does *also* act as a cache, but
> if you nullify that benefit it's only approximately a 10% slowdown
> even with a huge dbcache.
>
> With a fast SSD (e.g. NVMe) I think the difference between a 400MB
> cache and a 5GB one is "only" a halving of IBD time (when syncing from
> LAN peers).
>
> To prevent corruption the database updates must involve synchronizing
> writes.
>
> We changed how dbcache flushing worked with the explicit intention of
> making background flushing possible so that it could be concurrently
> flushing and processing blocks constantly rather than inserting these
> bubbles where it waits on the disk. Even though the consistency
> requirements make that possible now (the UTXO database doesn't have to
> be consistent except there is a record that states that all blocks
> before it have absolutely positively been applied to the database),
> actually making the change is still extremely complicated.
>
> Every time you process a block, once the cache fills you could flush
> out to disk the remaining dirty entries for the oldest remaining
> blocks until it's back under the limit again.. So essentially flushing
> every block in the background.  Then every once in a while, you do a
> disk sync and update the record that says where the completely
> consistent point is, without having to flush anything additional out.
> So almost no latency spikes at runtime.
>
> This would be good for mining but doing that requires a bunch of
> machinery to efficiently track things and probably would make sense to
> replace the dbcache's map with an open hash table of some kind at the
> same time to cut the malloc traffic down by 10x. I expect there is a
> factor of 2 IBD speedup waiting from these changes. I'm not sure if
> it'll ever happen though, it's a big complicated task and any mistake
> is a consensus bug.
>
> You can even do neat stuff like resolve collisions in the open hash
> table by displacing the oldest UTXO and once you've gone "far enough"
> flush. The table could run extremely close to completely full at all
> times.
>
> I'm personally fond of cuckoo tables. Where every item has a small
> number of possible locations like two random buckets which each hold 4
> items and if those locations are full you pick one, insert the item
> there, bump what was in that slot into one of its alternative
> locations.
>
> If the table has a little slack  (no more than ~95% full for 2 buckets
> of 4 items for example) then it's always successful at finding an
> empty slot after a few kicks. Lookup is extremely fast since you only
> need to do two random memory accesses. There are a bunch of different
> designs though most are best when you can keep the table <50% full but
> the cuckoo design is easy to take up to arbritarily high fullness.
>
> The STL sets that Bitcoin uses are a hash table, but collisions are
> resolved by having each entry in the hash table be a linked list, so
> every access involves several pointer chases and every insertion takes
> a malloc.